# can we create users in azure sql database which is running on free subscription?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I want to execute elastic queries on azure sql databases running on free subscription. So I need to create a user and login credential to do that. 
Can I create user in this subscription? Can I access master database from here using same subscription?

Comment: Have you tried it? This would be the fastest way to see if it's possible or not. You don't need access to `master` to create users, even in on-premises databases. You can use [contained databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-2017) to put the accounts in the database itself

Answer (score 0):

Can I create user in this subscription? Can I access master database from here using same subscription?

Yes, you can create the a user and login on the Azure SQL database.  And about these two questions, you can reference this document: [Controlling and granting database access to SQL Database and SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins). This Azure document will give you more details.

But if you want to use [Elastic Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview), you must give the user  sufficient permissions.
[image]

For more details, please see [Getting started with cross-database query (vertical partitioning)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical).

Hope this helps.